# How can I override Sass variables in Material Angular component styles?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, material-design, scss-mixins

I am searching for a whole now for result of my problem. In my company, I must style material design for our project, and this is so awkward that there is absolutely no way to style through sass variables (I mean, not only colours and fonts). I can't override lot of styles because of this impossible encapsulations etc. My work is so slow. If I could  override just variables like from _button-`base.scss` it would be not that much frustrating... I can't use `viewEncapsulation.none` like in lot of suggestions.

I don't know Sass very well so maybe I don't see the result. How can it be possible to not styling by variables, there are all here in material sass files.
I found only one answer like this:

```css
.mat-button {
  @extend %mat-button-base;
}
```

but this doesn't work for me. Anyone has other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should the angular-material site:
https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-usage-and-palettes

Option 1: change the $mat-indigo, $mat-pink and $mat-red to material palettes of your choice.

```css
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);


$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $candy-app-primary,
    accent: $candy-app-accent,
    warn: $candy-app-warn,  
  )
));


@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

**Option2**:
Override them by making your SCSS more specific.

**Option3**:
Use ::ng-deep to override specific components.

P.S. You really should NOT use `viewEncapsulation.none`.
That is the whole idea of angular which created encapsulated components.

Comment: thank you for answer. Option 1 is only about colors but I have the whole thing to style like borders, heights etc. I tried to make styles with ng-deep and also more specific but it isn't always working, I just waste my time all the time searching more and more specific selectors. :(

Comment: Why are you trying to change material? Their team spend loads of time and money to create something very good.
I suggest that if you must change some stuff that you keep it at a minimal.

Do you have an example html and css. this will help me help you

Comment: @ÖzcanDiler digging this up as I'm looking for this purpose - another lib/component has z-index higher than the cdk-overlay-container. The result is that a select input inside of this component won't show the options as they're lower in stacking order, my aim is to increase the z-index of the cdk-overlay-container.